# Why does my UITableView not respond to touchesBegan?

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview

I am using this method

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    if ([myPickerView isFirstResponder] && [touch view] != myPickerView) {
        [myPickerView resignFirstResponder];
    }
    [super touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}
```

but my tableView does not respond to touches (applied to the view works, but this is covered by the tableView!)

If this is not possible - is there any other possibility to capture "out of window" touches?

Comment: That's not how you write a `touchesBegan` method. It doesn't take your table view as the first argument.

Answer (score 12):

There is no such delegate method as `tableView:touchesBegan:withEvent:`. If you want to override `-touchesBegan:withEvent:` for your `UITableView`, you will need to subclass `UITableView`. Most problems like this are often better implemented with a `UIGestureRecognizer`. In the above, I'd probably use a `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

Answer (score 11):

I found the simplest way to do this is to add a gesture recognizer to the UITableViewController's view.

I put this code in the UITableViewController's viewDidLoad:

```
UITapGestureRecognizer * tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTap:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
```

And implemented the event handler:

```
- (void)handleTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    // your code goes here...
}
```

**EDIT:**
You could also add the gesture recognizer to the tableview, just change `[self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];` to `[self.tableView addGestureRecognizer:tap];`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a UITableView subclass solution that worked for me. Make a subclass of UITableView and override hitTest:withEvent: as below:

```
- (UIView *)hitTest:(CGPoint)point withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    static UIEvent *e = nil;

    if (e != nil && e == event) {
        e = nil;
        return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
    }

    e = event;

    if (event.type == UIEventTypeTouches) {
        NSSet *touches = [event touchesForView:self];
        UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
        if (touch.phase == UITouchPhaseBegan) {
            NSLog(@"Touches began");
        }
    }
    return [super hitTest:point withEvent:event];
}
```