# Can't add UITapGestureRecognizer to UITableViewController Inside a UITabbarController

Tags: ios, iphone, uitableview, uitabbar

I have an application which has a UITabBarController and Inside one of its items I have a UITableViewController and I want to add a UITapGestureRecognizer to view of UITableViewController.

Here comes my code:

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad  
{
[super viewDidLoad];
     UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyBoard:)];
        [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap];
}
- (void)dismissKeyBoard:(id)sender
{
        [self.view endEditing:NO];
}
```

**But dismissKeyBoard is never called!**
What should I do? and why it is not called?

Comment: You need to add tap gesture to UITableViewCell. Problem is that in UITableView u never touch to its view you always touch to UITableViewCell view.

Comment: You also have `endEditing` set to `NO` when it should be `YES`

Comment: @Shashi3456643 I did it but it didn't work!

Comment: @SASmith the main problem here is dismisskeyboard is never called

Comment: Can u check in ur debugger wether initWithFrame in UITableViewCell subclass  is called while loading UITableView. I hope u tried my answer

Comment: @AmirAbbasKashani check my answer. I have tested both just now and works fine. Do youhave any other uses for touch?

Comment: Check my answer, I solved it because you have `:(id) sender` in your call which isn't needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing whether you are using Storyboards, which these days most people do, have you dragged touch onto your view? It's just a secondary measure to confirm all bases are covered.

```
-(void) viewDidLoad{

    UITapGestureRecognizer *tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(dismissKeyBoard:)];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:tap]; 

}
```

`resignFirstResponder` is the usual call I make rather than endEditing.

**UPDATE** Something I have noticed is you are calling "sender" in your dismissKeyboard. Drop that.

```
-(void) dismissKeyboard{//**NO SENDER**, then it should work

    [self.textField resignFirstResponder];

}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8785184/touchesbegan-method-not-called-in-uitableviewcontroller-class-in-iphone

Comment: @AmirAbbasKashani did you remove :sender?

Comment: yes and it did work! How that happened? How did ":sender" prevent from calling "dismissKeyBoard" ?

Comment: Great. I am not sure tbh haha. Glad I could help :-)